# Best ux design for year selection in music chart radio/video app

Tags: navigation, menu, selection, modal-dialog

I have this website called billboard.fm where people can listen to the top 100 songs from each year and recently launched a responsive design at http://beta.billboard.fm that uses YouTube instead.

I have gotten feedback that it is hard to know where you can select the year from the top navigation. On the original site it was very simple because it displayed decade. What is the best user experience to help guide users to pick a year?

Comment: Hi @Jeff.  Welcome to the UX Stack Exchange! I've edited the tangential question about modals out of your post because its best to ask one question per thread.  Please feel welcome to repost a question about modals separately.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry about that, first post...I'm excited to learn from everyone.

Comment: +1 for great idea, I think I will find myself using this site more than normal :D

Comment: Thanks a lot! It doesn't get nearly as much traffic as the original site, but the videos really add a nostalgic value for me.

Comment: Is there a way to view lyrics ? I think it would be a nice addition

Comment: Well, the thing about lyrics is they are copyrighted, and you have to have permission to use them. There were some API's but it seemed kind of sketchy, I ended up just pulling song data from last.fm in the mean time.

Comment: I like the idea about a drop down presented by RK - http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/42148/3865, i think that's the most clear one. BTW, I'm curious about the project, why you changed to have YouTube only? Any thoughts about the Ads, how are you planing to display them? Although I know that's a topic for another thread.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback...it was initially made to be the mobile version since grooveshark (flash) wasn't supported on most mobile, however, it still isn't doing great for mobile, so I'm now thinking of having both sites and positioning this one as the video version. haven't thought about ads yet, just want to make it great first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that decade/year selection is one of the most important elements of the website. It certainly seems to be the most important *navigational* element. I personally feel that your current navigation and the other suggestions here have failed to recognise the real issue: that you haven't afforded the navigation enough screen space.

I think it would be better if you were to utilise more screen space for decade/year selection because it seems to be such an integral part of the site. The current solutions are trying to squeeze the navigation into a tiny space, and I think that's the wrong approach.

Something along these lines are my thoughts:

[image: Year Selection]

It looks and behaviours like a traditional menu, and I think is farily simple to use for most users. There's no learning curve needed to use it.

Comment: Dude, this is amazing. You brought a smile to my face, big time.... I love it.

Comment: @JeffCallahan If you like the answer, you should also upvote it ;)

Comment: I know...I was going to comment about that...I don't have a high enough reputation to vote yet, but when I do, I will.

Comment: And there also might be some mobile implications with this, but I think I may have to do a separate mobile menu no matter the case...any ideas for that?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this could be done.

[image]

If year is what you want to emphasize on you can add something(IDK what is its actual name) that scrolls automatically when mouse reaches towards the end. Considering the amount of motion there is on your site I believe this would be easy for you to implement.

Furthermore you can emphasize on the decade by like in this example boldening the text.Also you can make switching between decades easier by placing arrows which directly take you from one decade to another e.g 1980 to 1990. It would be really easy for the user to discover this.
Feel free to comment if all this doesn't make sense. I'll be happy to help

Here are some javascript/jQuery examples

http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/72yhW/2/

http://portfolio.robincwillis.com/ (hover over the left most portion)

http://robincwillis.com/_test/autoSlide/

More on this

http://www.robincwillis.com/AutoScroll/

> **Alternate**

Another simpler way to do it would be something like this

[image]

The dropdown allows selection of the decade and numbers from 0-9 allows selection of a particular year . On hover the box slides open to reveal the year completely, so for the user this would be easier to understand and use. (The white box denotes selected year)

Comment: I really like the way that looks, can you find any working examples online?

Comment: Here this is done in flash http://youtu.be/AK27oUrdHkg?t=8s . I think it'd be easy to translate into javascript. I'll find a javascript example too, I know I've seen it somewhere hang on.

Comment: Mentioned some examples in the answer.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much...my only concern though, is the implication for mobile devices, would it be swipe action at that point?

Comment: It'd be great if you can implement swipe action for the mobile version . Faded edges generally convey scrolling/swiping. But the thing is you will have to develop a different version of the site for mobile use as the auto scroll can cause problems. It's a problem if you're pursuing responsiveness. Otherwise it's ok, and there are many different free libraries available that can help you with the swiping pane.

Comment: Thanks, I like this idea as well, it's like the modal (sort of) but inline, the only challenge is getting it to work while maintaining the nav height, unless it overlayed.

Comment: Pushing The drop down way to the left in line with the numbers should solve the navheight problem . Or maybe I am interpreting your concern wrong here

Answer (score 1):

The year itself is not enough to make choice - use images, collages, photos for each year. Then place them into slider like this one - [FlowSlider](http://www.flowslider.com/example.html). So user can work only using his mouse for scrolling 'in time' :-)

*I'm not affiliated with FlowSlider's authors - it was just the first in google's response to me finding illustration for general idea.*

Comment: Thanks for the link, i do really like this idea conceptually, it just has some mobile implications which would be hard for me to manage.

Comment: +1, I thought of slide too. The decades showed as slides with artists photo mix and separate years are displayed as dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest visual cue will be to make it a narrative sentence. **The decade becomes a drop-down menu.** It is quite clear in the indication and also removes the un-necessary modal.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl4Bou.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

You can use the drop down for showing 60-70 years that you have. Since it is not a regular interaction (not something you do every couple minutes) you can have a longer drop down.

Else, you break it down into two parts: first part selects decade and second part selects year.

Comment: I really like this idea...but after you choose the decade from the drop-down menu, how do you go about choosing the actual year? Nested menus?

Comment: @JeffCallahan Ah, I missed that part. I did not know there were 2 levels in the modal. Updating the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I like that idea, as well, I am just pretty limited by the height of the nav bar...I initially had the drop down with nested menus, maybe it is worth another shot. The dial is also cool, but I'm afraid it will affect the height of the nav menu. Thanks for your help-these are really good ideas.

Comment: @JeffCallahan Just throwing out the last option ;) You do not really need to use the entire dial. Let the user click/type in the year.

Comment: That is better, can't believe I didn't think of it. I like that a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use calendar-like one-click year selector, which rolls out with mouse click (tap) on the current year control. On mobile just don't make transparent decade rows for high performance.
[image: year selector]

Comment: This is a really cool idea as well...this might be the best solution for mobile and solves the problem best with the current layout (with the year being displayed in the top navigation).